# Prompts.text - handle image/attachment response

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a bot dialog which asks a user for an order id:

```
bot.dialog("orderId", [
    (session, args, next) => {
       return builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please provide order id");
    },
    (session, results, next) => {       
        const matched = results.response.match(/\d{3}-?\d{7}/g);
        if (matched) {
           // ...
           session.endDialogWithResult(matched);
        } else {
           // ...
        }
    }
]);
```

This works as expected when user enters a valid order id and has validation
code which is omitted.

The problem i am facing is that users from time to time upload a screenshot
of the order id which triggers a default action which is just to re-prompt with a system prompt.

I know i can use [`retryPrompt`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ipromptoptions.html#retryprompt) property if the [`IPromptOptions`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ipromptoptions.html) interface, but this does not solve my issue.

I want to be able to start another dialog or end the conversation.
Any ideas how should i make this work ?

**Edit:**

In another case instead of saying "Yes" or any other positive phrase, user replies to `Prompts.text` with a "Thumbs Up" image from Facebook Messenger. which will also break `Prompts.text` flow.
I want to be able to treat the "Thumbs Up" image as a positive answer
to my question and control conversation flow according to that.

Answer (score 0):

As build-in Prompts will create a individual dialog, and `Prompts.text()` will verify the user input strictly for `string` type only, when you upload an image file to bot, which will not be verified by `Prompts.text()` dialog, and that raises your issue.

You can consider to add an step for your user to choice one approch to verify the code (by inputing code string, or uploading code picture).

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    (session) => {      
        const choices = ['code', 'image'];
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .text("Which will you prefer to provide your code?")
            .suggestedActions(
                builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session, [
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "code", "By Code"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "image", "By Image")
                    ]
                )
            );
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, choices);
    }, (session, args, next) => {
        const type = args.response.entity;
        session.send(`Your choice is ${type}`);
        if (type == 'code') {
            session.replaceDialog('verifyCode')
        } else {
            session.replaceDialog('verifyAttachmenet')
        }
    }
]);

bot.dialog('verifyCode', [(session) => {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Input your code');
}, (session, args, next) => {
    session.send(args.response);
    session.endDialog();
}])

bot.dialog('verifyAttachmenet', [(session) => {
    builder.Prompts.attachment(session, 'update your image');
}, (session, args, next) => {
    session.send(`You upload ${args.response.length} images`);
    session.endDialogWithResult(args.response);
}])
```

Comment: While this workaround may solve the current issue, it is not acceptable in various other situations like: Instead of saying "Yes" user replies to `Prompts.text` with a "Thumbs Up" image from Facebook Messenger. which will also break `Prompts.text` flow.